# How to create textfields using Foreach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to create Textfield every time i click on button, but when i use foreach to create that, when i write smth. in new textfield it is written also in others. I want that every new textfield will be different that i could write different thing in each of them.

This is what i am using.

```
@State var arr: [String] = []
@StateObject var homePageVM: HomePageViewModel = HomePageViewModel()

 ForEach(arr, id: \.self) { item in
                        TextField("text", text: item)
                    }
```

and in button click

```
Button {
                    arr.append($homepageVM.textfieldText)
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Read about [editable lists](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/building-editable-swiftui-lists/)

Comment: have a look at this post/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421104/how-do-i-create-a-certain-number-of-textfields-based-on-user-input/73423521#73423521

Comment: Search "ForEach TextField SwiftUI' on StackOverflow or Google and you'll find many results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct TextItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String = ""
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textItems: [TextItem] = []

    func addTextItem() {
        textItems.append(TextItem())
    }

    // funcs for loading and save model data
}

@StateObject var model = Model()

ForEach($model.textItems) { $item in
    TextField("text", text: $item.text)
}

Button("Add") {
    model.addTextItem()
}
```